# Can't separate columns when reading txt file

Tags: c, input, printf, scanf, out

Hi I managed to read txt files and printing them on the console window. I was given a task to select and sample a certain amount of data.

Example of txt file:

```
Voltage (V),Current (I),Power (W)
50,2,100,
51,2,102,
52,2,104,
```

etc.. How can I display only the column of Voltage and Power?

Comment: example : please show the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it work? How didn't it work? For the example input file, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: Explore `strtok()` or `strsep()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int V, I, W;//float ?
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while(fgetc(fp) != '\n')
        ;//skip first line

    while(3==fscanf(fp, "%d,%d,%d,", &V, &I, &W)){
        printf("V:%d, I:%d, W:%d\n", V, I, W);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```